# Custom sort function kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Can anyone please let me know how can we write our own function in javascript for sorting in kendo grid. And do we need to write two functions for asc and desc?

Any help.. greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it and you don't have to write two different function for ascending and descending since the only thing that you need to do is providing a [`compare`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.sortable.compare) function for the `column` field that you need a special algorithm.

Example:

Lets assume that we want to sort a grid by `name` (a `string`) and this is our data:

```
data    : [
    { id : 1, name : "john" },
    { id : 2, name : "jane" },
    { id : 3, name : "Jane" },
    { id : 4, name : "jack" },
    { id : 5, name : "jane" },
    { id : 6, name : "janette" },
    { id : 7, name : "John" }
],
```

and the columns definition as:

```
columns   : [
    { field: "id", title: "id" },
    { field: "name", title: "Name"}
]
```

What we get is:

```
id   Name
4    jack
2    jane
5    jane
3    Jane
6    janette
1    john
7    John
```

As we see we get it sorted alphabetically mixing lower and uppercase but lowercase always come before uppercase.

If we want to sort it first upper and then lowercase (ASCII order), we should define `columns.sortable.compare` for `name` as:

```
columns   : [
    { field: "id", title: "id" },
    { 
        field: "name", 
        title: "Name",
        sortable: {
            compare: function (a, b) {
                return a.name === b.name ? 0 : (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The `compare` function receives two items to compare.

Now, what we get is:

```
id   Name
3    Jane
7    John
4    jack
2    jane
5    jane
6    janette
1    john
```

You can try it both for ASC and DESC [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/EBSJQ/1/) Simple and neat!

Comment: thanks for the reply! But what I am doing is while getting the data to kendo grid, I am getting data from db on my page load for that particular page with particular page size(select FName, LName from Names limit 100, 200), and when am on page 3(Example) am able to sort only page 3 data but not based on the whole data.

Comment: According what you say, you should use [ServerSorting](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverSorting). Did you try it?