# Modify sorting in kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a column named 'IdleTime' which has values such as '59d 173', '23d 267' ,etc which represents n days and t time. But i wanted to sort this column by UpdatedTime as while sorting it considers IdleTime to be string and so the values aren't sorted properly.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("StudentModel")
    .Columns(column =>
    {
      column.Bound(p => p.ID).Width(30).EditorTemplateName("#=GetID(this)#");
      column.Bound(p => p.IdleTime).Width(30);
      column.Bound(p => p.UpdatedTime).Width(50);
    })
    .Selectable()
    .Sortable())
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set the default sort? Are you using a DataSourceRequest?

Comment: I want to use compare function mentioned in this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766764/custom-sort-function-kendo-grid) in Razor View format.

Comment: Based on [this](https://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-sort-example-for-mvc-wrappers) it is still not available in the wrappers, but you could do it with your client side example.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like compare (in JQuery Kendo) wasn't the only way to solve this problem for kendo MVC wrapper. To achieve this, I made use of ClientTemplate

```
column.Bound(p => p.UpdatedTime).Width(50).ClientTemplate("#=IdleTime#");
```

Comment: How does that impact sorting?

Comment: Column is binded to UpdatedTime so it will sort by it but it will still display IdleTime. Sorry I know this didn’t solve my actually question of custom sorting. I had to use this way because as said by you this wasn’t implemented on Kendo Grid MVC wrapper