# Kendo Grid Sorting issues for numeric

Tags: sorting, gridview, kendo-ui, numeric

I am using kendo grid to display data, but while sorting(ascending or descending) it's sorting perfectly for string values. But for numeric it's not sorting properly it's taking only first character to do sorting, not taking as string values even it's in numeric. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: You need to tell Kendo it's a number and not a string by setting the [schema model](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schemamodel)

Comment: sometimes it will comes with combination of both, how to sort in those criteria ? if string comes it's sorting properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766764/custom-sort-function-kendo-grid

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gird column [sortable.compare property](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.sortable#columns.sortable.compare) to assign your own compare function.

Then what you are looking for is a Natural sort, like the one described here: http://web.archive.org/web/20130826203933/http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1671288 and implemented here: http://www.davekoelle.com/files/alphanum.js

Here is a demo using a case insensitive version of the natural sort:
https://dojo.telerik.com/eReHUReH

```
 function AlphaNumericCaseInsensitive(a, b) {

    if (!a || a.length < 1) return -1;
    var anum = Number(a);
    var bnum = Number(b);
    if (!isNaN(anum) && !isNaN(bnum)) {
        return anum - bnum;
    }


    function chunkify(t) {
        var tz = new Array();
        var x = 0, y = -1, n = 0, i, j;

        while (i = (j = t.charAt(x++)).charCodeAt(0)) {
            var m = (i == 46 || (i >= 48 && i <= 57));
            if (m !== n) {
                tz[++y] = "";
                n = m;
            }
            tz[y] += j;
        }
        return tz;
    }

    var aa = chunkify(a ? a.toLowerCase() : "");
    var bb = chunkify(b ? b.toLowerCase() : "");
    for (x = 0; aa[x] && bb[x]; x++) {
        if (aa[x] !== bb[x]) {
            var c = Number(aa[x]), d = Number(bb[x]);
            if (!isNaN(c) && !isNaN(d)) {
                return c - d;
            } else return (aa[x] > bb[x]) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return aa.length - bb.length;
}



var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { id: 1, item: "item101" },
        { id: 2, item: "item2" },
        { id: 3, item: "item11" },
        { id: 4, item: "item1" }
    ]
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    sortable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "item",
        sortable: {
            compare: function(a, b) {
                return AlphaNumericCaseInsensitive(a.item, b.item);
            }
        }
    }]
});
```